# How to unregister a rancher app without removing the workloads?

Tags: rancher

I installed an application via the Rancher App UI. Now it appears under "App" as well as all the related parts under Workloads, Service, Ingress, etc. When I install an App via Helm, I see all the parts but no entry under "App".

Is there a way for me to "demote" the already installed App to a regular Helm app without having to first uninstall the Rancher App and then reinstall it via Helm?

In ArgoCD parlance, this would be something like "Delete App Do not Cascade". I understand that this functionality is not available in the Rancher UI, but there must be a CRD or similar. Does anyone know what that would be?

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same question I was able to achieve this kind of behaviour by changing the "spec.targetNamespace" of the App object.

My guess is that rancher in now applying the "helm delete" behind "app delete" in the wrong namespace

Feel free to try it and give me some feedback

```
# service "attached" to my rancher app
~$ kubectl get service test-api
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
test-api   ClusterIP   ...   <none>        80/TCP    30m

# Current target namespace in app (existing)
~$ kubectl get apps.project.cattle.io test-api -n x-xxx -o jsonpath='{.spec.targetNamespace}'
good-namespace

# Replace target namespace with non existing namespace
~$ kubectl patch apps.project.cattle.io test-api -n x-xxx --type=json -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/targetNamespace", "value": "dummy-namespace"}]'
app.project.cattle.io/test-api patched

# Current target namespace in app (non existing)
~$ kubectl get apps.project.cattle.io test-api -n x-xxx -o jsonpath='{.spec.targetNamespace}'
dummy-namespace

# Delete rancher App (hope for the best)
~$ kubectl delete apps.project.cattle.io test-api -n x-xxx
app.project.cattle.io "test-api" deleted

# service "attached" to my rancher app is still here
~$ kubectl get service test-api
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
test-api   ClusterIP   ...   <none>        80/TCP    31m
```